# reset git without trouble/waste time

Tags: git, github

I'm used to do git push from my machine to a git repository.

Then in remote server I do git pull from the same git repository.

Today a mentally challenged individual has messed with the files in server.

```
git pull origin master
U   index.html
U   static/css/app.css
M   static/js/app.js
Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.
Please, fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'
as appropriate to mark resolution, or use 'git commit -a'
```

I tried everything. Git reset, git hard reset, git rm those files, manually deleting those files. How can I fix this issue easily? I need to pull from master and I'm late already.

The solution in the provided link is unclear/doesn't work.

Comment: You have a merge conflict, you need to resolve that before you can continue. If you would just ignore it, you would leave the files in a broken state.

Comment: I don't mind. I just really need to do git pull and overwrite everything. Please help.

Comment: Did you read the answers to the linked duplicates?  Did you try them? If they didn't work, show which answers you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: Overwrite everything with what? You have two diverging and conflicting versions.